Product topology in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb R}$
Consider the product topology in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb R}$, for each $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ let define
\begin{equation}
       \mathbb{1}_A = 
        \begin{cases}
            1 & \text{if $x \in A $} \\
            0 & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
Now consider $\mathfrak{F} = \{\mathbb{1}_A$|  $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ such that $A$ is countable }. Prove that if $g : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ is the continuous function such that $g[\mathbb{R}] = \{1\}$ then $g \in \overline{\mathfrak{F}}$ but there is no sequence in $\mathfrak{F}$ that converges to $g$.
Firstly I am not sure if my interpretation for $\mathfrak{F} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb R}$ is correct. I think that for each $A$ that is countable, I have a uncountable choice for other characteristic functions.
I am aware that a countable union of countable sets is countable. How could I tackle this problem? Thanks.

What is $\mathbb{R}^R$?

@Malady product of $\mathbb{R}$-many copies of $\mathbb{R}$

@SassatelliGiulio I see that now. When I commented, those edits had not yet been made.

I don't know what you meant by "I am not sure if my interpretation for $\mathfrak{F} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is correct". $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is the space of all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and certainly every element of $\mathfrak{F}$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Now, onto the main question. $g \in \overline{\mathfrak{F}}$ can be proved by considering an open neighborhood $O$ of $g$. By definition of the product topology, there exists $r_1, \cdots, r_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ s.t.,
$$\{f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: |f(r_i) - g(r_i)| < \epsilon, \forall 1 \leq i \leq n\} \subseteq O$$
Since $g$ is the constant function $1$, $f = 1_{\{r_1, \cdots, r_n\}}$ belongs to the LHS, and thus $f \in O$. Clearly, $f \in \mathfrak{F}$ as well. This shows any open neighborhood of $g$ contains an element of $\mathfrak{F}$. By definition of closure, we see that $g \in \overline{\mathfrak{F}}$.
To prove there is no sequence in $\mathfrak{F}$ converging to $g$, assume to the contrary that $1_{A_i} \to g$, where $A_i$ are all countable. For any $r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \cup_i A_i$, we have $1_{A_i}(r) = 0$ for all $i$. As the topology is that of pointwise convergence, $g(r) = 0$ for $r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \cup_i A_i$ as well. Since $\cup_i A_i$ is countable, there are $r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \cup_i A_i$, contradicting the fact that $g$ is the constant function $1$. Hence, no such $A_i$ could exist.
Remark: By the same argument, one can show that $\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$ is actually the set of all indicator functions, but only those that are indicator functions of counatble sets - namely, those already in $\mathfrak{F}$ - can be limits of sequences in $\mathfrak{F}$.
